# any way make typescript .d.ts export full desc

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

if i have a code it auto create

```
export declare type IOptions = {
    allowNonNativeSlash?: boolean;
    allowNonNativeFlags?: boolean;
    throwError?: boolean;
};
export declare function parseRegularExpressionString(str: string, options?: IOptions): {
    source: string;
    flags: string;
    slash: string;
    input: string;
};
```

but i wanna it auto create like this

```
export declare type IOptions = {
    allowNonNativeSlash?: boolean;
    allowNonNativeFlags?: boolean;
    throwError?: boolean;
};

export declare function parseRegularExpressionString(str: string, options?: {
    allowNonNativeSlash?: boolean;
    allowNonNativeFlags?: boolean;
    throwError?: boolean;
}): {
    source: string;
    flags: string;
    slash: string;
    input: string;
};
```

any way can do this?

beacuse some time i feel when i import at other project, it will can't know what is options

---

and sometime when i do something like (not this code , but looks like)

```
function a()
{
let b: IOptions = {}
return b as IOptions
}
```

it will ask me write like this

```
function a(): IOptions
{
let b: IOptions = {}
return b
}
```

i i wanna a way can auto extract desc in .d.ts

Comment: The docs don't seem to say much. Are there any open issues on the GitHub repo?

Comment: `beacuse some time i feel when i import at other project, it will can't know what is options` -- can you give an example? It shouldn't cause problems...

Comment: @Aaron i can't find a easy way show this up